# ASPNETZERO: Impersonation is not working in AZURE

Tags: azure, impersonation, aspnetboilerplate

I have an ASPNETZERO application (v6.4.0.0) .NetCore + Angular. I have successfully deployed it to AZURE and all its features seems working fine but the Impersonation! The feature works fine while I run the app locally. I am also pretty sure that it use to work in azure before but all of the sudden has stopped working since this morning.

When I click the "Login as this user" option it redirects to "https://mywebsite/app/notifications?impersonationToken=dcb2e4f9-0813-4ce2-b6ca-2e66f76da0b4&tenantId=1" for a moment and then gets back to the admin account again. I suspect there is something wrong in the AccountAppService/Impersonate as the admin user does not get log out.

I wonder if there is any specific configuration is required in Azure in regards to Cache as the impersonation seems rely on it.

Comment: @aaron May I have you input on this? you have already saved me several times and I am looking forward to another one :)

Comment: Have you checked the **WebSiteRootAddress** key in the `Web.config`. Impersonation uses this address in order to create the proper URL and redirection.